# Combine arrays inside map according to label and sum data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with some streaming channel data, according to the shift (Morning and Afternoon).

I spent the night trying some functions like reduce, but I couldn't understand how it works and stagnated.

```
var array = [{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"55.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"50.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"25.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"50.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"10.00"},{"AppleTV":"11.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"9.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"5.00"},{"Nenhuma":"25.00"},{"Netflix":"20.00"},{"Outro":"50.00"}]}]
```

I expect to have this output:

The sum total of all streaming channels, divided by the amount of objects value per shift (morning and afternoon)

```
[{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"16.66"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"16.66"},{"Nenhuma":"16.66"},{"Netflix":"43.33"},{"Outro":"6.66"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"5.00"},{"AppleTV":"5.50"},{"HBO Max":"2.50"},{"Nenhuma":"36.00"},{"Netflix":"14.50"},{"Outro":"35.00"}]}]
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me, and if possible, explain.

Comment: could you tell the expected output?

Comment: I don't see a question in your post.

Comment: @ScottGnile Sorry, I will improve the question.

Comment: @hbg123 I will show how I intend to have the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's solve this problem in steps.
The first attempt is using `reduce` to iterate through the result and build something.
For simplicity let's get it to build an object where the `keys` represents the labels.
The reason for this is we can use this `key` to merge similar keys together.
On the TODO we observe that:

- The numerical values are strings not number and do not lend itself for arithmetic operations
- The subarray is difficult to merge and could do with a conversion to object as well

```js
let array = [{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"55.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"50.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"25.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"50.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"10.00"},{"AppleTV":"11.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"9.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"5.00"},{"Nenhuma":"25.00"},{"Netflix":"20.00"},{"Outro":"50.00"}]}];
let result = array.reduce( function (p, c, i, a) {
   let label = c.label;
   if (!(label in p)) {
       p[label] = c.data;
   }
   return p;
}, { } );
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));

// Output:
// {
//   "manha": [ { "Amazon Prime": "0.00" },
//              { "AppleTV": "0.00" },
//              { "HBO Max": "25.00" },
//              { "Nenhuma": "0.00" },
//              { "Netflix": "55.00" },
//              { "Outro": "20.00" }
//            ],
//   "tarde": [ { "Amazon Prime": "10.00" },
//              { "AppleTV": "11.00" },
//              { "HBO Max": "0.00" },
//              { "Nenhuma": "50.00" },
//              { "Netflix": "9.00" },
//              { "Outro": "20.00" }
//            ]
// }
```

For the second attempt, we will:

- convert more arrays to objects

  - as an object we can make use of object methods such as `in` to determine whether a key exists or not
- we can use parseFloat to convert strings to numbers
- we can start collating the information together
  This produces a nice set of raw data.

```js
let array = [{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"55.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"50.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"25.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"50.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"10.00"},{"AppleTV":"11.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"9.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"5.00"},{"Nenhuma":"25.00"},{"Netflix":"20.00"},{"Outro":"50.00"}]}];
let result = array.reduce( function (p, c, i, a) {
   let label = c.label;
   if (!(label in p)) {
       p[label] = { };
   }
   for (let i = 0; i < c.data.length; i++) {
       let e = Object.entries(c.data[i]);
       let k = e[0][0];
       let v = parseFloat(e[0][1]);
       if (!(k in p[label])) {
           p[label][k] = [ ];
       }
       p[label][k].push(v);
   }
   return p;
}, { } );
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));

// Output:
// {
//   "manha": {
//     "Amazon Prime": [ 0, 50, 0 ],
//     "AppleTV":      [ 0, 0, 0 ],
//     "HBO Max":      [ 25, 25, 0 ],
//     "Nenhuma":      [ 0, 0, 50 ],
//     "Netflix":      [ 55, 25, 50 ],
//     "Outro":        [ 20, 0, 0 ]
//   },
//   "tarde": {
//     "Amazon Prime": [ 10, 0 ],
//     "AppleTV": [ 11, 0 ],
//     "HBO Max": [ 0, 5 ],
//     "Nenhuma": [ 50, 25 ],
//     "Netflix": [ 9, 20 ],
//     "Outro": [ 20, 50 ]
//   }
// }
```

For the final step, we just average out the remaining array and convert the numerical result back to a string.

```js
let array = [{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"55.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"50.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"25.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"50.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"10.00"},{"AppleTV":"11.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"9.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"5.00"},{"Nenhuma":"25.00"},{"Netflix":"20.00"},{"Outro":"50.00"}]}];

let tmp = array.reduce( function (p, c, i, a) {
   let label = c.label;
   if (!(label in p)) {
       p[label] = { };
   }
   for (let i = 0; i < c.data.length; i++) {
       let e = Object.entries(c.data[i]);
       let k = e[0][0];
       let v = parseFloat(e[0][1]);
       if (!(k in p[label])) {
           p[label][k] = [ ];
       }
       p[label][k].push(v);
   }
   return p;
}, { } );

let result = Object.entries(tmp).map( ( [label, _data] ) => (
  { label : label,
    data: Object.entries(_data).map( function ( [k, v] ) {
       let obj = { };
       obj[k] = ( v.reduce( (p,c) => p + c ) / v.length ).toFixed(2);
       return obj;
    } )
  }
) );

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));

// Output:
// [
//   {
//     "label": "manha",
//     "data": [
//       { "Amazon Prime": "16.67" },
//       { "AppleTV": "0.00" },
//       { "HBO Max": "16.67" },
//       { "Nenhuma": "16.67" },
//       { "Netflix": "43.33" },
//       { "Outro": "6.67" }
//     ]
//   },
//   {
//     "label": "tarde",
//     "data": [
//       { "Amazon Prime": "5.00" },
//       { "AppleTV": "5.50" },
//       { "HBO Max": "2.50" },
//       { "Nenhuma": "37.50" },
//       { "Netflix": "14.50" },
//       { "Outro": "35.00" }
//     ]
//   }
// ]
```

Some final remarks on this answer compared to the question supplied.

- I used `toFixed(2)` which implements a round up

  - Answers show `"16.67"` instead of `"16.66"` for the "manha" averages
- For the "tarde" I got `"37.50"` ( i.e. `(50 + 25) / 2 === 37.50` ) instead of `"36.00"`
- All other values shown in the output matches to what is being requested in the question

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit longer then what you have hoped for but it should work.

```
let newAr = []
for(el of array) {
  const currentLabel = el.label
  let indexOfLabel = -1
  for(let i = 0; i < newAr.length; ++i) {
    if(newAr[i].label === currentLabel) indexOfLabel = i
  }
  if(indexOfLabel >= 0) {
    for(let i = 0; i < el.data.length; ++i) {
      const key = Object.keys(el.data[i])
      newAr[indexOfLabel].data[i][key] = parseInt(newAr[indexOfLabel].data[i][key])
      newAr[indexOfLabel].data[i][key] += parseInt(el.data[i][key])
    }
  } else {
    newAr.push(el)
  }
}

const occurrences = array.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  return acc[curr.label] ? ++acc[curr.label] : acc[curr.label] = 1, acc
}, {});

for(el of newAr) {
  for(data of el.data) {
    data[Object.keys(data)] = (data[Object.keys(data)] / occurrences[el.label]).toFixed(2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. I simply used hash grouping twice to create an intermediate object and create a final object at the end

```js
const data = [{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"55.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"50.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"25.00"},{"Nenhuma":"0.00"},{"Netflix":"25.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"manha","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"50.00"},{"Outro":"0.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"10.00"},{"AppleTV":"11.00"},{"HBO Max":"0.00"},{"Nenhuma":"50.00"},{"Netflix":"9.00"},{"Outro":"20.00"}]},{"label":"tarde","data":[{"Amazon Prime":"0.00"},{"AppleTV":"0.00"},{"HBO Max":"5.00"},{"Nenhuma":"25.00"},{"Netflix":"20.00"},{"Outro":"50.00"}]}]

const groups = data.reduce((acc, { label, data }) => {
  acc[label] ??= {};
  data.forEach((item) => {
    const [[channel, value]] = Object.entries(item);
    acc[label][channel] ??= [];
    acc[label][channel].push(Number(value));
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

// groups
//
// {"manha": {
//    "Amazon Prime": [0, 50, 0"],
//    "AppleTV": [0, 0, 0],
//    "HBO Max": [25, 25, 0],
//    "Nenhuma": [0, 0, 50],
//    "Netflix": [55, 25,50],
//    "Outro": [20, 0, 0]},
// ...}

const getFixedAvg = (data) => {
  const average = data.reduce((avg, e) => avg + e) / data.length;
  return (Math.floor(average * 100) / 100) // fix 16.67 to 16.66
    .toFixed(2); 
};

const makeData = (dataObj) => Object.entries(dataObj)
  .map(([channel, dataValues]) => ({ [channel]: getFixedAvg(dataValues) }));
  
const result = Object.entries(groups)
  .map(([label, dataObj]) => ({ label, data: makeData(dataObj) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```